# Is it possible to have two different audio outputs running simultaneously , one of them using HDMI and the other using Jack?

Tags: audio, multiple-monitors, arch-linux, vlc-media-player, xrandr

i am using a laptop and I have one LED TV attached to it,connected via HDMI to my graphics card (GTX 950)

I am using archlinux and I intend to run two different instances of vlc (or any other media player ) , Display one of them on my monitor screen and the other one on the TV,The Display problem is solvable after configuring xrandr to display both of my laptop monitor screen and the tv to work simultaneously side by side using this command (xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --right-of eDP-1 )

the problem is with audio , how can I set the first audio output to the TV through HDMI and the other one to the monitor through the analog sound card with jack .

I want to run two different audio outputs simultaneously .

I know xrandr is merging them into one big display and it's not multihead and when I used vlc it can't recognize both audio outputs simultaneously , i will appreciate any other ideas .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: idk the answer to your question as asked, but be aware that most solutions to this type of problem rely on your OS being able to recognise **two different apps** far more than two different output choices. Your 'quick fix' is usually use two identifiably different playback apps, for starters; the rest is fairly simple routing after that [but OS-dependant & idk nix well enough to suggest what to use for that part]

Comment: @Tetsujin ,thanks for your answer , I will look further into apps that could make this work depending on my OS .